# socket.io open port concern

Tags: node.js, security, socket.io, port

I have developed a live chat with socket.io. Now that all works well I am concerned about security. As far as I understand the next lines open port 3000 on my server.

```
 http.listen(3000, function(){
      console.log('listening on *:3000');
 });
```

If the port is open, anyone could just take a terminal and make a telnet request to that port. Is there a way to ask for a password or something to don't let everbody connect to the port? If there is, would my socket.io's app still works in the same way?
Forgive my ignorance, I'm not a security expert.

Comment: You probably did something like: var app = express();
var http = require('http').createServer(app); Note that the app is the only handler in the server so it can only do that one thing. Bad users can, however send arbitrary number of requests so DDOS is your only problem.

Comment: Yes, anyone with some smarts can connect to your server.  That's how the internet works.  You need to make sure they cannot do anything harmful.

Comment: @jollarvia how do I prevent DDOS attacks on that port? Is there a module that can protect me against?